# jquery nth-child selector problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I want to select images in a div. The images i want are number 2,5,8,11 etc.

```
$('.thediv img:nth-child(3n+1)')..
```

Did not work for me, did i miss something? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the HTML markup? You might have tags around each `img`, in which case they are all the first child of their parent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your formula `3n + 1` doesn't work because these are the elements that will be selected for the following values of `n`:

```
3(0) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
3(1) + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4
3(2) + 1 = 6 + 1 = 7
3(3) + 1 = 9 + 1 = 10
...
```

Clearly, these aren't the 2nd, 5th, 8th, 11th ... elements selected. Each of them is off by 1. You need to use the formula `3n + 2` instead, so these elements will be selected:

```
3(0) + 2 = 0 + 2 = 2
3(1) + 2 = 3 + 2 = 5
3(2) + 2 = 6 + 2 = 8
3(3) + 2 = 9 + 2 = 11
...
```

And since you said in your comment that each `img` is in an `a`, the `:nth-child()` pseudo-class should be attached to `a`, then you select the `img`:

```
$('.thediv a:nth-child(3n+2) img')
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that they are wrapped in an a-tag. tried .thediv a img:nth... but it doesnt work.

Comment: @fille: So `div` contains a bunch of `a` tags? See if my edited answer helps you.